# How to setup htaccess to run codeigniter from CLI?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter application that i am trying to run via CLI but its not working. I used the example of codeigniter docs and I am using HMVC with no index.php on url.

I notice that the script via cli stop working after I removed index.php with .htaccess.

Any ideas on what might be the problem and how to solve it?
Thank´s all of you guys for the help.

This is my htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And my script

```
<?php
class Tools extends MX_Controller {

        public function message($to = 'World')
        {
                echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```

Now my script is located in application/modules/tools/controllers/Tools.php

So I run it on the terminal as follows

```
$ cd /path/to/project;
$ php index.php tools message
```

Comment: I don't think `.htaccess` is related with CLI file access. After all, all htaccess rules are around URLs and not system paths. Maybe you must call `php index.php Tools message` (case sensitive if on Linux)

Comment: yeah tried that but no luck :(

Comment: Explain what you mean by `script via cli stop working`.

Comment: I mean it was working but stopped working after i added htaccess, but I solve th problem , thank you justinas !

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro, i think you get right url.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you dev87 for the help, I found the problem and it had nothing to do with htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Well after several day struggling with this problem I found what was wrong, it had nothing to do with htaccess.

The constructor on the class was checking if the user was logged in, since the user that php runs on was not it stop execution of the script.

And I would like to mention, the htaccess sample that dev87 provides is the correct one we should use on codeigniter, not the one I am using.

Thank´s for the replies guys!